Rank deleted after suspension
My account was recently unfairly suspended after a personal dispute with a moderator BobJansen. I received all reputation back but my profile is no longer in the 2014 year ranking:
http://stackexchange.com/leagues/91/year/quant/2014-01-02
I was ranked #1 in 2014, as can also be seen by the 2015 ranking which states the change of ranking from last year.
I wrote to stackexchange support but received no answer.
I want my 2014 rank immediately restored or I will take legal action against the responsible moderator and stackexchange. The rank must be restored by 30. September 2015.

Yeah I'm really not in any position to know what's going on in the background here. Can you check again in a couple of days? I believe some of these stats are refreshed periodically only. 

I will check again on September 30, and the 2015 rank is already updated so I think its permanent.

Ok let's try again at the end of the month. Otherwise it might just be a bug, I simply don't think it's possible to ban someone from rankings.

Yes, the stackexchange support last week finally replied that they ordered a developer to restore my rank.

So was it purposefully removed? I've never even seen such an option so I'm very surprised

I guess it's a side-effect from the suspension as that recalculates reputation, and I assume it's a bug: when the suspension is over it would make sense to undo all the effects of the suspension as the term suspension suggests it's only a temporary measure. I see that as of this moment the ranking has been restored by (someone at Stack Exchange corporate or automatically by a batch job) so I guess they agree this isn't intended behaviour.


I want my 2014 rank immediately restored or I will take legal action against the responsible moderator and stackexchange. The rank must be restored by 30. September 2015.

I can understand why you are upset, but I'm not sure the moderators can help in this instance.  Your name is still on all the answers you gave so you can still point people to your answers to show your abilities.
I really doubt Stack exchange is going to get involved here.  
As to the moderators helping, I don't think they can.  This is how the stack exchange engine works.  They've done the same sort of suspension to some high profile stack overflow users so I don't think they are going to bend the rules here for you :(
Why do you feel your rank is so important that you'd take legal action to get it restored?   If its that important then I should get my butt in gear to increase mine!!

I have a permanent contract with a law firm to defend me on any issues.
